# alternative to import module and import from module

Tags: python, import, module

In python since   "import module"  and   "form module import something" uses the same amount of memory,  Is there a way to only load "something"?

The only alternative I see is to make a module that has just "something" and import that.

Comment: how about 'import module.something'?

Comment: for example: 
import math.pi  throws 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math.pi'; 'math' is not a package

Comment: okay, you are right. It seems like modules are loaded as a whole. However, if it is really important for your case you may change this behavior by overwriting the import system: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is just do
`import module.something`
like JDornheim commented, or you could only import one thing from the module, using
`from module import something`,
but if you're concerned about the size of the module causing loading issues, I don't think there's a better way to load in modules.